# OpenCV acceleration (OpenCL) of gaussian blur

Tags: opencv, opencl, gaussianblur

I'm porting an image post-processing library to OpenCV, and testing the `UMat` OpenCL acceleration features.

First tests work quite well, with complex filters using lots of arithmetic and math operations, I have a consistent speed increase (such as x2 to x4) with `setUseOpenCL(true)` vs `setUseOpenCL(false)`. So far so good.

However, `cv::gaussianBlur` suspiciously offers the exact same performance, such as a 1500ms time for a 4096x4096 image and a 321x321 pixels kernel, with and without OpenCL.

So I suspect it's not using OpenCL in my case, but why?

Comment: What is your OpenCL device? If you're running OpenCL on your CPU, then it can't make computational performance beyond that whichyour CPU can provide which a well optimised program would use anyway.

Comment: Step into `gaussianBlur` in a debugger and see which one of the many different implementations you'll end up in (just for OCL there are at least 3 for `uint8_t` that I could see, depending on the kernel size and other things). I have a feeling that the giant kernel is not helping here.